# Remove alert dialog border With Custom Theme

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

[image]

In my application i am using alert dialog with rounded rectangle theme.But it have alertdialog rectangle and my theme.My problem is how to replace alert dialog border like dialog.I want to show this set item with own theme only.

I want output this manner instead of the above theme:

[image]

**Main Activity:**

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertSeverity = new AlertDialog.Builder(
           getActivity(), R.style.Theme_CustomDialog);
     alertSeverity.setTitle("Severity Status");
CharSequence[] severityStatus = { "Low-Severity",
           "Middle-Severity", "High-Severity" };
     alertSeverity.setItems(severityStatus,
           new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {        

              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
                 });
```

**My Theme:**

```
<style name="Theme.CustomDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/shapedialogtheme</item>
<item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>

</style>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  >

<solid android:color="#565656" />

<stroke
    android:width="5dp"
    android:color="#ffff8080" />

<corners android:radius="30dp" />

<padding
    android:bottom="10dp"
    android:left="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"
    android:top="10dp" />
<size 
    android:width="150dp"
    android:height="150dp"/>

</shape>
```

[image]

Comment: u can make it easily by making it custom instead of using themes.

Comment: wait i m going to post code.

Comment: check this http://postimg.org/image/g7kht5lt7/ @Satheesh

Comment: I dont need this output.i want above one like below one...Because i am using setitems which is only added alert dialog

Comment: this is custom alert which i have just made.

Comment: ya indiandroid i accept this one but i want load items dynamically low severity,medium severity,highseverity using setItems.So which is not support custom dialog it support only alert dialog.so how to remove the alert dialog border

Comment: means u r using list-view in dialog?

Comment: yes if you use alertdialog.setItems() this data automatically converted in listview manner...

Comment: there is no way to apply round border to alert dialog using themes u must have to use customized alert dialog...Google it u will find solution.

Answer (score 6):

Use Dialog instead of AlertDialog.

Create your custom layout which you want to show in dialog and setContent in dialog.
Apply this theme `android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar` in dialog it will hide border.

Here is sample code.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);

// your layout file
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

// for hide title 
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

//for set title
dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");


dialog.show();
```

**Updated:**

just tried this in AlertDialog.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertSeverity = new AlertDialog.Builder(
           getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
```

Comment: hey i want set items in dynamically so i definitely used alertdialog instead of dialog..

Comment: @Satheesh check my updated answer if it will not work then you have to use dialog..you can also take listview in layout..

Comment: kk i understand but i am using function   alertSeverity.setItems(severityStatus,
           new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {        

              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
                 }); which is used only alertdialog not dialog.

Comment: its k suppose i want to add datepicker dialog so at that time what i do

Comment: Hmmm try this **android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar** for that if It will not work then better to ask another question for that...

Comment: k i understand android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar is used to remove the alert dialog border but i am setting a own theme for this how do solve this...

Comment: You can also create your own theme and set parent as this theme...[link1](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html), [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614707/android-xml-theme-inheriting-from-two-parent-themes)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35333/discussion-between-satheesh-and-capdroid)

Answer (score 2):

try the next solution:

extend from dialog, and set the exact view to use by using setContentView .

the alertDialog is used for some functionalities. it's not that it can do anything you want.

maybe instead of extending you could take the dialog and then use the setContentView.

Answer (score 2):

Use Dialog instead of AlertDialog

```
Dialog callAlert = new Dialog(LoginActivity.this,R.style.CutomDialog);  
callAlert.setContentView(R.layout.call);
```

Style.xml

```
<style name="CutomDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/Animations.DialogAnimation</item>
</style>
```

call.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_margin="20dp"
 android:background="@drawable/call_bg"></RelativeLayout>
```

call_bg.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#A20B3F" />

<corners android:bottomRightRadius="4dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp" 
 android:topLeftRadius="4dp" android:topRightRadius="4dp"/>
```

Main thing is that you have to make layout backgrpund transparent otherwise you will not able to get output as you want.

Answer (score 2):

You need to design a custom dialog for this purpose :

```
**dialog.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_view_SaveAs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/save_as"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_txt_SaveAs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:maxLength="50"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="@string/save_as" />

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_SaveAs"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:layout_margin="3dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:layout_margin="3dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can then make different class for the particular dialog like this:

```
public class SaveDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {

private Context context;

private TextView txt_view_SaveAs;
private EditText edit_txt_SaveAs;
private Button btn_SaveAs;
private Button btn_Cancel;

public SaveDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    setCancelable(true); // Setting the Dialog to be Cancellable on Back Key Press

    txt_view_SaveAs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_view_SaveAs);
    edit_txt_SaveAs = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_txt_SaveAs);
    btn_SaveAs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_SaveAs);
    btn_SaveAs.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_Cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Cancel);
    btn_Cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        // Write code for all the buttons on click methods
}
}
```

Then you can call the custom dialog in your main class by using the following code :

```
SaveDialog save_dialog = new SaveDialog(saving_activity);
save_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
save_dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can not remove border from alert dialog.**

use this

```
public class ActivityIndicator extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{
protected static final String TAG = InfoIndicator.class.getName();
ImageView close;
WebView info;

      public ActivityIndicator (Context context,String information) 
       {
          super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
          requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
          setContentView(R.layout.info);
          setCancelable(true);
           }
}
```

and try this below function for show, hide and clear dialog

```
private static ActivityIndicator activityIndicator;

public static void hideActivityViewer() {
    if (activityIndicator != null) {
        activityIndicator.dismiss();
    }
    activityIndicator = null;
}

public static void showActivityViewer(Context context) {
    if (activityIndicator == null)
    {
        activityIndicator = new ActivityIndicator(context);
    }
    activityIndicator.show();

}
public static void clearDialogs()
{
    activityIndicator = null;
}
```

Comment: Hai i want to display my custome theme only without alertdialog border

Comment: make layout and set in extends Dialog class

Comment: k suppose if i am using Date picker dialog and then set my custome theme for that...which is also visible the first image manner so whenever i am not remove the alert dialog border...

Comment: sorry,, i didn't get you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35410/discussion-between-satheesh-and-sanket-kachhela)

Answer (score 1):

you can use popwindow for more style by yourself