# Showing custom view inside AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-custom-view

I have a class that extends LinearLayout. It contains simply two EditBox. On some button click, i want to load this class inside the alert Dialog. When i click on button, the alert dialog is displayed but the view class that extends LinearLayout is not displayed.The code is as follows. I am stucked into this. Can I get some solution??

```
public class StudentDialog extends LinearLayout {
    Context context;
    LinearLayout layout;

    public StudentDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        createStudentDialog();
    }

    private void createStudentDialog() {

        layout = new LinearLayout(context);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        layout.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        layout.setId(200);

        EditText studentName = new EditText(context);
        studentName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        studentName
                .setTextAppearance(getContext(), TEXT_DIRECTION_FIRST_STRONG);

        EditText address = new EditText(context);
        address.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        address.setTextAppearance(getContext(), TEXT_DIRECTION_FIRST_STRONG);

        layout.addView(studentName);
        layout.addView(address);

    }

}

//Now i am calling this on some button click listener as follows. The alert dialog is displayed but not the StudentDialog. 

StudentDialog dialog = new StudentDialog(this);



        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialog);

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: please follow this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18224754/942224 in this you have extends Dialog instead of View and just create object of that class and you can use show to view as dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you change

```
alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialog);
```

as

```
alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialog.layout);
```

Comment: or you could remove the "layout" variable from your StudentDialog class since it is already a LinearLayout. You can add the views to "this" from inside the createStudentDialog function. Then it would work as expected. What you are doing in your original code is that you add the editTexts to one layout and add a different layout to the AlertDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to show two edit text in a alert view just like a login dialog with button, if yes then just create a layout which you want to show in dialog view. Create a class which extends Dialog and set this layout in setContentView of onCreate  of this class