# Run a custom Dialog layout using Theme/Style

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I need to run a custom dialog layout using only theme/style options. Running custom Dialog layout by code is not an option for me. I think this should be possible by mean of attributes `"android:layout", "android:dialogLayout", "*android:dialogCustomTitleDecorLayout", "*android:dialogTitleIconsDecorLayout", "*android:dialogTitleDecorLayout".<br/><br/>`
My Activity onCreate load layout in a Dialog Style:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.MyDialog);
    setContentView(R.layout.mydialog);
    this.setTitle("A title");
}
```

style xml:

```
<style name="MyDialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/MyDialog.WindowTitle</item>
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/dialog_title</item>
    <item name="android:dialogLayout">@layout/dialog_title</item>
    <item name="*android:dialogCustomTitleDecorLayout">@layout/dialog_title</item>
    <item name="*android:dialogTitleIconsDecorLayout">@layout/dialog_title</item>
    <item name="*android:dialogTitleDecorLayout">@layout/dialog_title</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDialog.WindowTitle">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance_WindowTitle</item>
 </style>


<style name="TextAppearance_WindowTitle">
    <item name="android:textSize">32sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@+color/verdeTI</item>
</style>
```

Please, note that Text colour of the title is correctly applied (@+color/verdeTI) so I am confident the cascading styling is right but it seems none of the layout options work at all because I continue to see the standard Dialog Layout. My "dialog_title" use a completely different ImageView for divider so I can be sure when it is loaded.
The custom divider is just the main reason because I need a different layout.

**Update 15/4/2014**

[Android theme Guide stats:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

*Some style properties, however, are not supported by any View element and can only be applied as a theme. These style properties apply to the entire window and not to any type of View. For example, style properties for a theme can hide the application title, hide the status bar, or change the window's background. These kind of style properties do not belong to any View object. To discover these theme-only style properties, look at the R.attr reference for attributes that begin with window. For instance, windowNoTitle and windowBackground are style properties that are effective only when the style is applied as a theme to an Activity or application. See the next section for information about applying a style as a theme.*

**OK attributes starting with "window" are applied only in Themes not in Styles. What's about *Layout attributes ? When they are applied ?**

Comment: I am curious, what do these "star" prefixes mean and why do you use it? In `*android:dialogCustomTitleDecorLayout` - does this `*` symbol has any significance in android style framework?

Comment: Somewhere I saw this is the way to reference private android properties not accessible directly (without *)

Comment: Truly, this is. Useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can try by passing `ThemeName` as `argument` of `constructor` like this way.

```
public class TestDialog extends Dialog{

    public TestDialog(Context context) {
        super(context, R.style.YourTheme);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Add window feature if you require.

Make object of this class in any Activity so you can use Dialog property.

:-
More info https://stackoverflow.com/a/18224754/942224

i was using this way. so it may be help you.

Comment: Bounty is almost closed so I give you my kudos accepting your replay as "best" solution. Actually I would prefer have a global solution using Theme settings to have customized all AlertDialog, ProgressDialog, ecc. . With your solution I still have to manage my activties run as Dialog (setting the Theme like in my sample)

Comment: Once you create AlertDialog and ProgressDialog class as per theme. than you can use in any activity and you can also use in any project. create object and use dialog properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by creating your required layout file and opening it with an activity class just in the manifest add this code to your activity

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.                    Dialog"
```

But you will be getting title bar in your dialog with this which is your label name for your activity. To remove it add this code before setContentView

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.  FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: setting theme in manifest activity is OK but the same effect of my setTheme() in code, instead I need (custom) title bar in every Dialog to be opened in app. My question is more simply: override default Dialog Layout is possible by style or not ? If not which is the use of "android:*Layout" style properties ?

Comment: if you want a different title bar and create a new style with base style as theme.dialog and do the required modifications in it. I am sure you will get what you want with that

Comment: Not completely true. I need here a custom divider under the title text. It is NOT stylable therefore the question

Comment: You can try adding it in your layout at the starting.

Comment: I'm looking for a app-wide solution. I wish choose a Theme for app that include "android:dialogLayout" customized and all Dialogs run in app look the same style. I cannot imagine that every activity have to inject a custom divider in Dialog by code.