# Background color of dialog

Tags: android, background, dialog

I'm using the following layout for dialog window:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:colorBackground="#ff0000">
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webViewNote1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:colorBackground="#ff0000" />
```

As you can see I tried to change the color in the RelativeLayout and in the WebView but nothing happen and I still have a white background.

Any idea how to change background in regular dialog (not alert dialog)?

Comment: Use a custom Dialog... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389446/android-webview-changing-backcolor-and-font-color

Comment: You should also take a look at the css of the webview, and investigate how is it possible to have a totally transparent background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply background color in `parent view of webview`. and make webview background transperent like this way.

```
mWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

**EDIT:**

How to make custom Dialog?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18224754/942224

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23109450/942224

Comment: Thank you very much. It succeeded. But the title is still white. Do you know how to change it too?

Comment: The dialog title view cannot be changed, neither skinned, it's an annoying android thing. But there are workarounds you can find by googling for them.

Answer (score 0):

change

`android:colorBackground="#ff0000"`

to

`android:background="#ff0000"`

for your `RelativeLayout`