# How to use colors from android standard themes?

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to create custom controls and stylize them according to current theme. How can I access colors and drawables in standard system themes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android XML theme inheriting from two parent themes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614707/android-xml-theme-inheriting-from-two-parent-themes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to retrieving colors like colorPrimary or colorPrimaryDark from your theme dynamically, then let's say your theme looks something like

```
 <style name="AppTheme.OrangeTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/orangeDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/orangeAccent</item>
</style>
```

You can access primaryColor from styledAttributes using this method

```
public static int getPrimaryColorFromSelectedTheme(Context context) {
    int[] attrs = {R.attr.colorPrimary, R.attr.colorPrimaryDark};
    TypedArray ta = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
    int primaryColor = ta.getColor(0, Color.BLACK); //1 index for primaryColorDark
    //default value for primaryColor is set to black if primaryColor not found
    ta.recycle();
    return primaryColor;
}
```

Similarly, you can also access colorAccent as well, by adding it to the attributes.

About the drawables, I don't quite understand what you mean by accessing drawables in standard system themes. But you can access Android drawables using

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, android.R.drawable.[Drawable Name]);
```

Comment: Note: you should always use [ContextCompat.getDrawable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getDrawable(android.content.Context,%20int)) instead of `getResources().getDrawable()` - it was built such as to work appropriately on all API levels.

Comment: Where can I find a documentation for all theme attributes colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark..., etc.?

Comment: You can find the attributes in Android source code. Here's the link for [AppCompat theme attributes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.attr.html)