# Is it possible to combine multiple styles into one?

Tags: android, android-styles

I have two styles, call them A and B. Is it possible to either:

1. Apply both of them to the same UI element, or
2. Combine both of them into a single style (basically just to allow me
   to accomplish point 1)

I know that styles can inherit from parents, so I could do something like making a style C that inherits from A, and copy all of the attributes from style B into style C. But that rather defeats the point of what I'm going for - I've grouped my styling into styles A and B to avoid duplicating code, and copying attributes into C completely ruins that.

Comment: Styles do not support multiple inheritance. Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614707/android-xml-theme-inheriting-from-two-parent-themes

Answer (score 0):

Inheriting multiple styles is not supported. However, you can create a base style that has everything that is in common in `A` and `B`. Then inherit from it.

```
<style name="SuperTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <!--All the attributes that A and B will have in common. -->
</style>

<style name="A" parent="SuperTheme">
    <!--Unique attributes only in A. -->
</style>

<style name="B" parent="SuperTheme">
    <!--Unique attributes only in B. -->
</style>
```

Comment: That doesn't address my concern. I'm looking for a way to combine all properties of styles A and B into one. Basically I'm looking for a style that's a union of A and B, while your example uses a style that's an intersection of A and B. Unfortunately that doesn't help.

Comment: @Mark Since there is no multiple inheritance of styles then you have to do the union of A and B yourself. However, the moment you start to do that you will notice you have a design smell as you will lose flexibility. I still recommend my approach.

Comment: your approach does nothing to solve the problem I stated. To illustrate this, let me ask you the following question: How would you apply all attributes of both styles A and B to a single view, using your approach?

You seem to simply be espousing style inheritance generally, and while it is a useful design in some situations, it's completely orthogonal to my question.

Comment: @Mark It seems that the problem you stated is outside the scope of Android as there is no multiple inheritance of styles. I wish you the best and I cannot wait to see what solution you come up with, please post it as an answer once you do.

Comment: There might be a way to do it programmatically

Comment: @NewtronLabs yes, I believe it is. Thanks for the suggestions though :) I couldn't come up with any solution better than duplicating the attributes across two styles, albeit with a comment that said "This style should remain a union of the two styles above". ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah, there might be. For my case, though, I was just looking for something easy to do in XML. Having to set it in code is too much extra bother to be worth it for me.

Answer (score -2):

I found that declaring two independent styles and then creating a single style which references style A & B in the name will allow you to merge the two styles.

e.g.

```
<style name="A"/>
<style name="B"/>
```

Can be merged by creating:

```
<style name="A.B"/>
```